# Installing pylibmc on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, memcached, pip, libmemcached

When running

```
pip install pylibmc
```

on Ubuntu, I get the following error:

```
_pylibmcmodule.h:42:36: fatal error: libmemcached/memcached.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: The package for CentOS 5 is **libmemcached-devel**.

Answer (score 9):

Zags answer didn't do the trick for me on Ubuntu 13.10. libmemcached-dev had already been installed. I had to also do:

> sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev

Maybe that will help someone else.

Answer (score 4):

**Install libmemcached using below command**

```
sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev
```

**Then set the environment variable and install**

```
LIBMEMCACHED=/opt/local pip install pylibmc
```